# If I have Ubuntu on a usb, and install it will it remove windows?

Tags: usb

So Windows Vista is on my hard-drive and Ubuntu is on my USB. If I were to install Ubuntu when my USB is in, would it just fully install it on  my USB or would it override windows?

Comment: You can't install Ubuntu to the same USB drive you booted it from. On how to install to an USB drive see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key

Answer (score 3):

If you have Ubuntu on your USB as a Live-USB, when you start the Live session and choose to Install Ubuntu on your hard-drive you have two choices:

1. Let Ubuntu use all your drive space (therefore, overriding Windows)
2. Install it alongside Windows.